How to Filter WordPress Posts by Date and Price Using Custom Meta Data?
I'm working on a WordPress project where I've added a custom meta data field called 'date_price' to posts. This meta data field contains arrays with the following structure:
array(
    array('from_date' => '01.02.2024', 'to_date' => '15.03.2024', 'price' => 2500),
    array('from_date' => '15.03.2024', 'to_date' => '10.05.2024', 'price' => 3500),
    array('from_date' => '10.05.2024', 'to_date' => '31.09.2024', 'price' => 5000)
)

Now, I'm trying to implement a filtering system where users can filter posts based on date and price. For example, users should be able to filter posts for a specific date like April 12 2024, and also filter posts with a price lower than 3000.
What would be the most efficient way to achieve this functionality? Any guidance or code examples would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Add a form with two input types on the front end. You can get the value below.
$selected_date = isset( $_POST['filter_date'] ) ? sanitize_text_field( $_POST['filter_date'] ) : '';
$max_price = isset( $_POST['max_price'] ) ? intval( $_POST['max_price'] ) : 0;

// Assuming 'd/m/Y' format is used in the frontend
$selected_date = date('d.m.Y', strtotime($selected_date));

Now use the below query to filter the post.
$args = array(
    'post_type'      => 'post', // Adjust post type as needed
    'posts_per_page' => -1, // Retrieve all posts
    'meta_query'     => array(
        'relation' => 'AND', // Combine meta queries with AND logic
        array(
            'key'     => 'date_price', // Custom meta field name
            'value'   => $selected_date, // Date to filter
            'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
            'type'    => 'DATE',
        ),
        array(
            'key'     => 'date_price', // Custom meta field name
            'value'   => $max_price, // Price threshold
            'compare' => '<=', // Compare prices less than or equal to the threshold
            'type'    => 'NUMERIC',
        ),
    ),
);

$query = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( $query->have_posts() ) :
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
        // Output post content or perform other actions
        the_title();
    endwhile;
    wp_reset_postdata();
else :
    // No posts found
    echo 'No posts found.';
endif;

